# LINQ: Improving performance of "query to find all dictionaries from list of dictionaries where given key has at least one value from list of values"

Tags: performance, linq

I tried searching for existing questions, but I could not find anything, so apologize if this is duplicate question.

I have following piece of code. This code runs in a loop for different values of `key` and `listOfValues` (`listOfDict` does not change and built only once, `key` and `listOfValues` vary for each iteration). This code currently works, but profiler shows that 50% of the execution time is spent in this LINQ query. Can I improve performance - using different LINQ construct perhaps?

```
// List of dictionary that allows multiple values against one key.
List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> listOfDict = BuildListOfDict();

// Following code & LINQ query runs in a loop.
List<string> listOfValues = BuildListOfValues();
string key = GetKey();

// LINQ query to find all dictionaries from listOfDict
//    where given key has at least one value from listOfValues.
List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> result = listOfDict
            .Where(dict => dict[key]
                    .Any(lhs => listOfValues.Any(rhs => lhs == rhs)))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: How about reversing the problem? Create a dictionary with all the values you want to search for, where the value is a list of matching dictionaries?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Extract all the values out of those dictionaries, and create a dictionary with those values as keys, and the value of each of those keys in that dictionary would be a list of all the dictionaries that value was found in. Then it's a matter of just looking up one of the values in that dictionary.

Comment: You would probably need to involve the keys of those dictionaries as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `HashSet` will perform significantly better. You can create a `HashSet<string>` like so:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> strings = ...;
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(strings);
```

I assume you can change your methods to return `HashSet`s and make them run like this:

```cs
List<Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>> listOfDict = BuildListOfDict();

HashSet<string> listOfValues = BuildListOfValues();
string key = GetKey();

List<Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>> result = listOfDict
            .Where(dict => listOfValues.Overlaps(dict[key]))
            .ToList();
```

Here `HashSet`'s instance method [`Overlaps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.overlaps?view=netframework-4.8) is used. `HashSet` is optimized for set operations like this. In a test using one dictionary of 200 elements this runs in 3% of the time compared to your method.

Comment: I will try that... looks promising.

Comment: Apologize for delay in responding, but it was a little big change to move from `List` to `HashSet`. But after changing code to `HashSet`, I was able to improve performance by more than 50%. Thanks for the suggestion. I will also try the solution suggested by NetMage and post results.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: Per @GertArnold, switched from `Any`/`Contains` to `HashSet.Overlaps` for slight performance improvement.

Depending on whether `listOfValues` or the average value for a `key` is longer, you can either convert `listOfValues` to a `HashSet<string>` or build your list of dictionaries to have a `HashSet<string>` for each value:

```
// optimize testing against listOfValues
var valHS = listOfValues.ToHashSet();
var result2 = listOfDict.Where(dict => valHS.Overlaps(dict[key]))
                        .ToList();

// change structure to optimize query
var listOfDict2 = listOfDict.Select(dict => dict.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.ToHashSet())).ToList();
var result3 = listOfDict2.Where(dict => dict[key].Overlaps(listOfValues))
                        .ToList();
```

Note: if the query is repeated with differing `listOfValues`, it probably makes more sense to build the `HashSet` in the dictionaries once, rather than computing a `HashSet` from each `listOfValues`.

Comment: Funny, this `ToHashSet` method always escaped my attention. For the record, I also tried Contains and found that Overlaps performs slightly better.

Comment: @GertArnold You mention not remembering `ToHashSet` (which I had as a personal extension before it was added to .Net) - I didn't know about `Overlaps` :) Presumably it is optimized to use `HashSet` internals more efficiently. Update: Looking at the source, it appears `Overlaps` uses the public `Contains`, so perhaps the efficiency is in not calling a lambda as `Any` does.

Comment: Performance of this suggestion was very close to the answer by @GertArnold. Thank you both for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

@LasseVågsætherKarlsen suggestion in comments to invert the structure intrigued me, so with a further refinement to handle the multiple keys, I created an index structure and tested lookups. With my Test Harness, this is about twice as fast as using a `HashSet` for one of the `List<string>`s and four times faster than the original method:

```
var listOfKeys = listOfDict.First().Select(d => d.Key);
var lookup = listOfKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => listOfDict.SelectMany(d => d[k].Select(v => (v, d))).ToLookup(vd => vd.v, vd => vd.d));
```

Now to filter for a particular key and list of values:

```
var result4 = listOfValues.SelectMany(v => lookup[key][v]).Distinct().ToList();
```